# Firebase Data Retrieval (Random key)

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here I just retrieval data from Firebase and printed in (Log). I need to display in a `Listview` or `RecyclerView`. I referred to lots of websites, blogs, videos etc. but still I haven't found a proper solution.

**Printed LOG screen shot :**
[image]

**Firebase Structure:**
[image]

[Problem video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2rPvuSnD6CeZUU1UnF5eEphN2hlNGlDRG9DUG1ZeG5DY3RV/view?usp=sharing)

I need solution or proper website to solve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to show list of employee or want to access particular employee's data form filling the form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data of employee personal detail. Data is a string and pass in the code below:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext())
    {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        JSONObject jsonItem = json.getJSONObject(key);

    }
```

You will have jsonobject for each item.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create model class for your `DataSnapshot` so you can use like this.

**Model Class:**

```
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName;

/**
* Created on 31/3/18.
*/
public class Employee {

@PropertyName("Employee Address")
public long emplyeeAddress;
@PropertyName("Employee Age")
public long emplyeeAge;
@PropertyName("Employee Blood Group")
public long emplyeeBloodGroup;
@PropertyName("Employee Date of joining")
public long emplyeeDOJ;
@PropertyName("Employee Gender")
public long emplyeeGender;
@PropertyName("Employee ID")
public long emplyeeId;
@PropertyName("Employee Married Status")
public long emplyeeMarriedStatus;
@PropertyName("Employee Name")
public long emplyeeName;
@PropertyName("Employee Phone Number")
public long emplyeePhoneNumber;
@PropertyName("Employee Qualification")
public long emplyeeQualification;

String key;

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Address")
public long getEmplyeeAddress() {
    return emplyeeAddress;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Address")
public void setEmplyeeAddress(long emplyeeAddress) {
    this.emplyeeAddress = emplyeeAddress;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Age")
public long getEmplyeeAge() {
    return emplyeeAge;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Age")
public void setEmplyeeAge(long emplyeeAge) {
    this.emplyeeAge = emplyeeAge;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Blood Group")
public long getEmplyeeBloodGroup() {
    return emplyeeBloodGroup;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Blood Group")
public void setEmplyeeBloodGroup(long emplyeeBloodGroup) {
    this.emplyeeBloodGroup = emplyeeBloodGroup;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Date of joining")
public long getEmplyeeDOJ() {
    return emplyeeDOJ;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Date of joining")
public void setEmplyeeDOJ(long emplyeeDOJ) {
    this.emplyeeDOJ = emplyeeDOJ;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Gender")
public long getEmplyeeGender() {
    return emplyeeGender;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Gender")
public void setEmplyeeGender(long emplyeeGender) {
    this.emplyeeGender = emplyeeGender;
}

@PropertyName("Employee ID")
public long getEmplyeeId() {
    return emplyeeId;
}

@PropertyName("Employee ID")
public void setEmplyeeId(long emplyeeId) {
    this.emplyeeId = emplyeeId;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Married Status")
public long getEmplyeeMarriedStatus() {
    return emplyeeMarriedStatus;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Married Status")
public void setEmplyeeMarriedStatus(long emplyeeMarriedStatus) {
    this.emplyeeMarriedStatus = emplyeeMarriedStatus;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Name")
public long getEmplyeeName() {
    return emplyeeName;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Name")
public void setEmplyeeName(long emplyeeName) {
    this.emplyeeName = emplyeeName;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Phone Number")
public long getEmplyeePhoneNumber() {
    return emplyeePhoneNumber;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Phone Number")
public void setEmplyeePhoneNumber(long emplyeePhoneNumber) {
    this.emplyeePhoneNumber = emplyeePhoneNumber;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Qualification")
public long getEmplyeeQualification() {
    return emplyeeQualification;
}

@PropertyName("Employee Qualification")
public void setEmplyeeQualification(long emplyeeQualification) {
    this.emplyeeQualification = emplyeeQualification;
}
}
```

**Value Listener:**

```
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        if (data != null && data.getValue() != null && data.getChildrenCount() > 0) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapShot : data.getChildren()) {

                Employee emplyess = snapShot.getValue(Employee.class);
                emplyess.setKey(snapShot.getKey());
            }

        }
        //set your list to adapter

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

I hope it's will help you :-)

**Note :** May be i made some spell mistake in employee attribute name so please double check it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can display the employee names in a `ListView` using an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Employee personal detail");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String employeeName = ds.child("Employee Name").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(employeeName);
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```